# Virtualmin updates Debian 8 to Debian 9 stretch/sid

Tags: debian, virtualmin

Today i saw that there are ~1000 updates listed in Virtualmin.
I decided to update all, and now surprise surprise - running on debian 9 stretch/sid.

Did i something wrong? Furtunately i created an snapshot before updating.

**My question now, can i run debian 9 without problems ? For now, all seems to be working fine.** [debian version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVTD1.png)

If not, i will roll-back the snapshot, but can someone say me how to setup NOT to dist-upgrade again.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The updates module in Virtualmin/Webmin never does a dist-upgrade (it doesn't even know how). But, if one were done before from the command line, or if you were already on the rolling unstable ("sid") distribution, you would get upgrades like this whenever a new release is forked by the debian folks. In that case, I think you were already running unstable, it just hadn't been forked into "9" yet. At least, that's how I understand it. I'm not really an expert on Debian and apt. But, I do know about Virtualmin.

If everything is still working, I probably wouldn't do anything (rolling back can be tricky, too). On Debian, we don't provide many binaries, just a bunch of Webmin modules packaged as debs, and most things will work across version changes without much trouble. There will be pain in the future, as they change things...it's impossible to predict what will change, however. Newer versions of things (like MySQL, PHP, Apache, Dovecot, Postfix, ClamAV) often require changes and updates within Webmin and Virtualmin in order to work. We try to stay on top of changes, but sometimes it can take as long as a few weeks to show up in the next release.

Also, you may need to update paths in Webmin for some of your services. If you find yourself looking at a "X does not appear to be installed on your system" warning, and you know it is there, you'll need to re-configure the module to point to the right location for the config files, start/start commands, etc. The switch to systemd has already happened in Debian 8, so the biggest change was already in place, and Webmin has supported systemd for a while.

Finally: You're now on the bleeding edge of Virtualmin development (and Debian development). So you're going to have to be an active participant, or end up in a messy situation. While we don't support Debian 9 yet (we don't support new distros until they are officially released, because a moving target is much harder to hit), you can file tickets about new versions of software that comes along if they break things. e.g. if MySQL 5.7 or MariaDB 10 rolls into the repo and onto your system and something breaks, let us know about it in our bug tracker. Our answer will probably be "it'll be fixed in the next release of Webmin/Virtualmin", but we *may* also be able to provide workarounds until then.

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I work on Virtualmin/Webmin.